# Android onOptionsItemSelected is not functioning

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I'm working on go-back function with my fragments. I use the action bar as return button but the function onOptionsItemSelected does not work (the function may be even not called)

This code is in my FragmentActivity:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {          
                getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);//disable the back button
                this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tab);

        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.bottom_tab_host);

        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.bottom_tab_content);

        //tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("explore").setIndicator("explore"), ListTabWidget.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("browse").setIndicator("browse"), SearchList.class, null);
    }
```

And this code is in my Fragment(A):

```
            public class SearchList extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    FragmentActivity searchActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        searchActivity = (FragmentActivity) this.getActivity();

        View searchView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list, container, false);

        SearchView searchBar = (SearchView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.browse_search);

        searchBar.setIconifiedByDefault(false); //Showing text field in search
        searchBar.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return searchView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH, null, searchActivity, BrowseGrid.class);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);

        startActivity(intent);*/
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("search_query", query);

        BrowseGrid browseFragment = new BrowseGrid();
        browseFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.bottom_tab_content, browseFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

and Fragment(B):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        return view;
    }
```

The aim is very simple. Pressing the back button, Fragment goes back from B to A.
Am I missing something?

Comment: try to Log.d() inside the onOptionsItemSelected and check if it prints

Comment: It does print something but still not going back to previous fragment

Comment: post your activity code.

Comment: Good News(Maybe) I have tried adding FragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() to observe. I found that it actually has nothing can pop!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found that the stack actually has nothing to pop(I wanna know why...), I choose an alternative to do so.

I don't know whether it is the best solution but it seems work.

replace

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

to

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
                //Log.d("Bottom Tab", "popping backstack");
                fm.popBackStack();
            } else {
                //Log.d("Bottom Tab", "nothing can pop");
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
```

Even the stack has nothing, it will override the onBackPressed() to go back.

Answer (score 0):

How about try using the SupportFragmentManager on both Activity and Fragment(A)

currently the Fragment (A) is using

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

While in you activity onOptionsItemSelected is using

```
this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

change it to:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: Just to figure out the cause of your problem fist. Try not using the FragmentTabHost. Directly add fragment(A) to your and test the code of home button pressed first. I guess it works properly.

Comment: I use FragmentTabHost just because I have got plenty of choices...others are being deprecated....

Comment: I understand your limitation but this is just to test the code first. Internally FragmentTabHost also uses the FragmentTransaction to attach/detach each fragment you added to the tabHost. So, I think the code you wrote should work properly without the FragmentTabHost.

Comment: If it is the case that the FragmentTabHost cause the problem. You might have to consider to use another activity to display Fragment(B).

Comment: I have tried not using tab.....but it comes up with more errors and even cannot experiment

Answer (score 0):

Change this line , as you are handling the `FragmentTransaction` from `Fragment` class not `Activity` itself. You need to get `getParentFragment()` first.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

To

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.bottom_tab_content, browseFragment);
```

Comment: a NullPointerException occured...;(

Comment: @Simon try like getActivity().getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.bottom_tab_content, browseFragment);

Comment: getActivity() does not have getParentFragment().

Comment: the null pointer exception maybe tell that the fragment does not have parent fragment